# SCIM PATCH library

Tags: node.js, provisioning, scim, scim2

I am implementing SCIM provisioning for my current project, and I am trying to implement the PATCH method and it seems not that easy.

What I read in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#page-32) is that SCIM PATCH is almost like JSON PATCH, but when I look deeper it seems a bit different on how the path is described which doesn't allow me to use json-patch libraries.

example:

```
"path":"addresses[type eq \"work\"]"

"path":"members[value eq
              \"2819c223-7f76-453a-919d-413861904646\"]"
```

Do you know any library that is doing SCIM PATCH out of the box?
My project is currently a node project, but I don't care about the language I can rewrite it in javascript if needed.

## Edit

I have finally create my own library for that, it is called `scim-patch` and it is available on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scim-patch) https://www.npmjs.com/package/scim-patch

Comment: I finish by making my own library for that, it is available here https://github.com/thomaspoignant/scim-patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not found any typescript library to implement scim patch operations, I have implemented my own library.

You can find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/scim-patch

Answer (score 1):

I implement SCIM PATCH operation in my own library. Please take a look [here](https://github.com/imulab/go-scim/tree/new_model/src/core/expr) and [here](https://github.com/imulab/go-scim/tree/new_model/src/protocol/crud). It is currently a work in progress for v2, but the CRUD capability required by patch operations has matured.

First of all, you need a way to parse the SCIM path, which can optionally include a filter. I implement a finite state machine to parse the path and filter. A scanner would go through each byte of the text and point out interesting events, and a parser would use the scanner to break the text into meaningful tokens. For instance, `emails[value eq "foo@bar.com"].type` can be broken down to `emails`, `[`, `eq`, `"foo@bar.com"`, `]` and `type`. Finally, a compiler will take these token inputs and assemble it into an abstract syntax tree. On paper, it will look something like the following:

```
emails -> eq -> type
        /   \
     value  "foo@bar.com"
```

Next, you need a way to traverse the resource data structure according to the abstract syntax tree. I designed my property model to carry a reference to the SCIM attribute. Consider the following resource:

```
{
   "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"],
   "userName": "imulab",
   "emails": [
      {
         "value": "foo@bar.com",
         "type": "work"
      },
      {
         "value": "bar@foo.com",
         "type": "home"
      }
   ]
}
```

I start traversing from the root of the resource and find the child called `emails`, which will return a multiValued property of complex type. I see my next token (`eq`) is the root of a filter, so I perform the filter operations on the two elements of `emails`. For each element, I go down the `value` child and evaluate its value. Since only the first element matches the filter, I finally go down the `type` child of that complex property and arrive at the target property. From there, you are free to perform `Add`, `Replace` and `Remove` operations.

There are two things I recommend to watch out.

One thing is that you traversing path will split when you hit a multiValued property. In the above example, we only have one elements that matched the filter. In reality, we may have many matches, or there could be no filter at all, forcing you to traverse all elements.

The other is the syntax of the SCIM path. The specification mandates that it is possible to prefix the schema URN in front the actual paths and delimit them with a `:`. So in that representation, `emails.type` and `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User:emails.type` are actual equivalents. Note that the schema URN contains dots (`.`) in the `2.0` part. This creates further complication that now you cannot simply delimit the text by `.` and hope to get all correct tokens. I use a Trie data structure to record all schema URNs as **reserved words**. Whenever I start a new segment in the path, I will try to match it in the Trie and not solely rely on the `.` to terminate the segment.

Hope it will help your work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at scim2-filter-parser: https://github.com/15five/scim2-filter-parser

It is a library mainly used by the authors' django-scim2 library: https://github.com/15five/django-scim2

It relies on python AST objects, but I think you should get some takeaways from there.

Comment: I have checked these resources and finish by made SCIM patch by myself.
I may publish a typescript library for that, when all my tests are done.